# Fast way to convert a byte[] string to its Integer value

Tags: java, optimization

I am reading a large file from disk. That file just contains numbers, encoded as plain old ASCII. At the moment, I am reading in chunks, and then doing something like this:

```
byte[] token;  // bytes representing a bunch of numbers
int n = Integer.parseInt(new String(token));
```

In other words, I am converting to a String and then parsing the String to Integer. I would like to know if there is a way to use fast operations like shifting and binary arithmetic instead?

I suspect that this could be made faster. For example, the raw bytes for the numbers 1,2,3 are 49,50,51. Any ideas for hacks?

Comment: How are the numbers delimited in the input file?

Comment: Does it have any negative integers?

Comment: @Perception: no need to worry about that, I've already handled the delimination. I'm splitting out byte[] chunks as fast as possible.

Comment: @kuriouscoder: good question, no negatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    int n=0;
    for(byte b : token)
        n = 10*n + (b-'0');
```

Comment: If you read a stream of ascii characters the order is already taken care of, right, or I am missing something?

Comment: There's no endian issue here. however, will some culture write lowest digit first? Say in Arabic, we see things like `عام 2013 هو عام جيد`. We know Arabic is written right-to-left, so here the Arabic number is written with lowest digit first? No idea.

Comment: This looks quite promising! Order isn't an issue, it's left to right as expected. Also, no foreign language tricks to worry about. I'll test it in a bit and let you know :)

Comment: Thanks! For interest, this resulted in a roughly 28% speedup.

Comment: how to convert this back to string to byte array ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do binary arithmetic exactly with base 10 numbers, but you can do decimal arithmetic. Assuming that higher-order digits come first:

```
byte[] token;
long n = 0;
long pow = 1;
for( int i = token.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
  n += (token[i]-48) * pow;
  pow *= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    byte[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] += '0';
    }
    int n = Integer.parseInt(new String(a));
    System.out.println(n);
```

output

```
123
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as my original approach. I didn't want the extra overhead of creating new Strings and then parsing them to ints.